# Julia plot hline! doesn't work with multiple threads

Tags: plot, julia

I have a simple simulation and I want to plot errors on 3 distinct figures. To speed things up I wanted to introduce a little bit of parallel computing.

```
Threads.@threads for i in 1:3
plt = plot(t, err[:, i], linecolor=:blue, label=[""], linewidth=3)
hline!(plt, [0], linestyle=:dash, linecolor=:black, label=[""])
xlabel!(L"t")
ylabel!(L"e_%$i")
savefig(plt, "fig/Staubli_Slotine_Li$i.pdf")
end
```

Everything stops working when I try running julia with `-t3` flag

```
ERROR: LoadError: TaskFailedException
Stacktrace:
 [1] wait
   @ ./task.jl:334 [inlined]
 [2] threading_run(func::Function)
   @ Base.Threads ./threadingconstructs.jl:38
 [3] top-level scope
   @ ./threadingconstructs.jl:97

    nested task error: KeyError: key :annotations not found
    Stacktrace:
      [1] pop!(h::Dict{Symbol, Any}, key::Symbol)
        @ Base ./dict.jl:587
      [2] pop_kw!(dd::RecipesPipeline.DefaultsDict, k::Symbol)
        @ RecipesPipeline ~/.julia/packages/RecipesPipeline/F2mWY/src/utils.jl:57
      [3] _update_subplot_args(plt::Plots.Plot{Plots.PGFPlotsXBackend}, sp::Plots.Subplot{Plots.PGFPlotsXBackend}, plotattributes_in::Dict{Symbol, Any}, subplot_index::Int64, remove_pair::Bool)
        @ Plots ~/.julia/packages/Plots/nzdhU/src/args.jl:2058
      [4] _subplot_setup(plt::Plots.Plot{Plots.PGFPlotsXBackend}, plotattributes::Dict{Symbol, Any}, kw_list::Vector{Dict{Symbol, Any}})
        @ Plots ~/.julia/packages/Plots/nzdhU/src/pipeline.jl:277
      [5] plot_setup!(plt::Plots.Plot{Plots.PGFPlotsXBackend}, plotattributes::Dict{Symbol, Any}, kw_list::Vector{Dict{Symbol, Any}})
        @ Plots ~/.julia/packages/Plots/nzdhU/src/pipeline.jl:138
      [6] recipe_pipeline!(plt::Any, plotattributes::Any, args::Any)
        @ RecipesPipeline ~/.julia/packages/RecipesPipeline/F2mWY/src/RecipesPipeline.jl:87
      [7] _plot!(plt::Plots.Plot, plotattributes::Any, args::Any)
        @ Plots ~/.julia/packages/Plots/nzdhU/src/plot.jl:208
      [8] plot!(::Plots.Plot; kw::Base.Pairs{Symbol, V, Tuple{Vararg{Symbol, N}}, NamedTuple{names, T}} where {V, N, names, T<:Tuple{Vararg{Any, N}}})
        @ Plots ~/.julia/packages/Plots/nzdhU/src/plot.jl:198
      [9] plot!(; kw::Base.Pairs{Symbol, V, Tuple{Vararg{Symbol, N}}, NamedTuple{names, T}} where {V, N, names, T<:Tuple{Vararg{Any, N}}})
        @ Plots ~/.julia/packages/Plots/nzdhU/src/plot.jl:188
     [10] #xlabel!#484
        @ ~/.julia/packages/Plots/nzdhU/src/shorthands.jl:416 [inlined]
     [11] xlabel!
        @ ~/.julia/packages/Plots/nzdhU/src/shorthands.jl:416 [inlined]
     [12] macro expansion
        @ ~/Documents/studia/master_thesis/master_thesis_code/sym_scripts/Staubli_Slotine_Li.jl:29 [inlined]
     [13] (::var"#88#threadsfor_fun#1"{UnitRange{Int64}})(onethread::Bool)
        @ Main ./threadingconstructs.jl:85
     [14] (::var"#88#threadsfor_fun#1"{UnitRange{Int64}})()
        @ Main ./threadingconstructs.jl:52
in expression starting at /home/jcebulsk/Documents/studia/master_thesis/master_thesis_code/sym_scripts/Staubli_Slotine_Li.jl:26
```

If I comment out `hline!` the script runs without any issue.

It looks like I can't have both `hline` and parallel operation.

Answer (score 0):

On my machine I am getting an `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` which is even uglier. For sure in your code `xlabel!(L"t")` and `ylabel!(L"e_%$i")` mutate the global state which is very bad for any kind parallelism and should be `xlabel!(plt, L"t")` and `ylabel!(plt, L"e_%$i")`.

However, in many scenarios this might still not work because `Plots.jl` is also maintaining it's global state and it might be not thread safe. Hence the best way to go forward is through distributed computing:

```
using Distributed
addprocs(3)
@everywhere using Plots, LaTeXStrings
Distributed.@distributed for i in 1:3
plt = plot(t, err[:, i], linecolor=:blue, label=[""], linewidth=3)
hline!(plt, [0], linestyle=:dash, linecolor=:black, label=[""])
xlabel!(L"t")
ylabel!(L"e_%$i")
savefig(plt, "fig/Staubli_Slotine_Li$i.pdf")
end
```

Note that you will have a better performance if the plots are very complex as each of those subprocesses will experience the "Julia time to first plot" issue.

Hence before going multi-process you might want to parametrize the GR backend and see if the performance is sufficient:

```
using Plots
ENV["GKSwstype"]="nul"  # this parameter significantly speeds up generation of GR-based plots
gr()
```